# Rails: Bootstrap Accordion not collapsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Here's my code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <% @workspace_tasks.each do |t, a| %>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%= t.to_s %>">
            <%= t %>
         </a>
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse<%= t.to_s %>" class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">  
          <table class="table table-striped">
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am setting the ID for the panel to be in line with the Key for the hash which I am looping through.

The information is displayed correctly, however, if I set the panel by default to be expanded, I cannot collapse it.  The inverse is true too where I cannot expand the panel if I set to to collapsed by default.

I us identical code elsewhere in my app but with a different Model being used to create the hash in the Controller.  I find this behavior very strange.

I'm not sure whether it is my code?  Or something with Bootstrap?

Comment: What is value of `t`? Does it contain spaces?

Comment: Yes, it contains space.  Is this problematic? It is all within " " so I thought the spaces would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The HTML5 specifcation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) states that id cannot contain spaces:

> When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element’s tree and must contain at least one character. **The value must not contain any space characters.**

You need to prepare `t` variable to be a valid id, e.g. by replacing spaces with `-`:

```
t.to_s.gsub(/\s/, '-')
```

Or by using [`parameterize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize):

```
t.to_s.parameterize
```